# Куб на с++ (с библиотекой SFML)

Tags: c++, sfml

Программа должна выводить куб и вращать его. Пишу на системе 64х, но программа на 32х. Пути библиотеке указал.

Вот ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
#include <gl/glu.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace sf;

int main() {
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "Minecraft C++");

    Texture t;
    t.loadFromFile("resources\background.jpg");
    Sprite background(t);

    GLuint texture = 0;
    {
        Image image;
        image.loadFromFile("resources\texture.jpg");

        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixelsPtr());
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glClearDepth(1.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90.f, 1.f, 1.f, 500.f);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    Clock Clock;
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        float time = 30;
        float size = 20.f;

        window.pushGLStates();
        window.draw(background);
        window.popGLStates();

        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -100);
        glRotatef(time, 50, 50, 0);








        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);   glVertex3f(-size, -size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);   glVertex3f(size, -size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3f(size, size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);   glVertex3f(-size, size, -size);
        glEnd();


        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-size, size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(size, size, size);
        glEnd();


        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(-size, size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-size, size, size);
        glEnd();


        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(size, size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(size, size, -size);
        glEnd();


        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, -size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size, -size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(size, -size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-size, -size, -size);
        glEnd();


        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size, size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(size, size, -size);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(size, size, size);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-size, size, size);
        glEnd();

        window.display();
    }

    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
    return 0;
}
```

А если подключить библиотеку `#include <gl/glu.h>` , то появляются ошибки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без `#include <gl/glu.h>`  у тебя нет  нужных языку C++ объявлений для работой с либой (структур, классов, констант и т.д.). Компилятор C++ их просто не видит.

Поэтому тебе выдаются ошибки `C3861` и т.д., полагаю, это ошибки компилятора (никогда не компилировал под виндой)

Когда ты подключаешь `glu.h`, программа компилируется - поскольку для компилятора доступен весь нужный исходный код, но появляются ошибки LNK*. Это ошибки линкера. Значит ты не подключил скомпилированную библиотеку для работы с opengl

тебе нужно линковать твою программу с правильной библиотекой. Гугл на вопрос `link glu.h windows` выдает вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939495/5006740)

Comment: ....  Благодарю! :)

Comment: ну, я надеюсь, заработало

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема. У меня она заключалась в том, что у меня не было библиотеки [opengl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL). Просто скачай ее, установи в visual studio, все строки "glu" начнут работать.